# Why did the water stop a few hours after my Culligan reverse osmosis filter change?

Tags: water, filter

How do I change the Aqua-Cleer Culligan reverse osmosis filters (the sediment and the carbon ones, the leftmost two of the four)?

Why did the water stop few hours after my change?

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: no clear description of the system ... no clear description of any observations ... no mention of any filter change procedure

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](https://www.culligan.com/CulliganCom/media/products/AquaCleer_Drinking_Water_System_Owners_Guide.pdf) has this under Install Filter Cartridges (I ignored the "lubricate" part as it did not make sense to me),

> Twist the cartridge to lock it into the manifold. 
>   See Figure 2. [image]

1. I turned the incoming water pipe tap off (from the along-the-pipe position to the across-the-pipe one).
2. To remove the filters, I twisted them counter-clockwise (looking from the bottom up) and pulled them out.
3. To put the new ones in, I removed the cellophane from their tops, removed their lids and twisted them in clockwise.
4. Turned the incoming water pipe tap back on.

The drinking tap in the kitchen had water for few hours after that, then stopped.

1. Suspecting an issue with incoming water supply, I removed the cover of the filter shelf, removed the steel holder above the incoming tube, pulled out the tube with its plastic cuff, got a bowl ready, turned the incoming tap on for a second and saw the water gushing.
2. Suspecting a blockage between the filters, I removed the two filters, forced the leftmost (sediment filter) manifold open by rotating it with a screwdriver (taking care not to inflict damage).  Opening the incoming tap for a second pushed water through the manifold.  Closing it off and opening the manifold for the carbon filter showed no water.  (In retrospect I guess this happened because I closed off the sediment socket).
3. Suspecting an issue with the Automatic Shut-Off (ASO) valve located between the two filters, I removed the top cover, removed the screws, pulled it out, at which moment a few liters of water gushed from the opening (emptying the bladder-pressured tank).

The investigation steps above turned misdirected.  After talking with a local Culligan salesperson, I followed their advice and **twisted the filters harder in** (clockwise looking from the bottom up).  As soon as I turned the incoming tap on, I heard the water filling the filter system.  The drinking water tap in the kitchen had water couple hours after that.

Comment: On my RO system (iSpring) it requires that after filter change(s) that you flush the system to ensure the carbon dust and sediment is out prior to going into the membrane. You might be ok, but if your water slows down in production you might need to change the RO membrane out as well. My system has a hose I disconnect from the last filter of the pre-RO (filter 3) that I put into a bucket and flush the system until I see no more gray water.

Comment: Usually about 3-5 gallons before it clears, another reason for this flush is to check for leaks on the filter housings and to be sure that water flows though them. I assume at this point your system is back to functioning properly?

Comment: I did not flush the system other than letting the drinking tap run for a minute.  I have no idea if my system has the RO membrane.  It seems reasonable for an RO system to have one...  Thanks for the comments, the system runs OK.

Answer (score 0):

Sharp Water has it.

**Removing the old cartridges:**

1. Turn off inlet feed water valve.
2. Release each cartridge from manifold by making a counter-clockwise, quarter turn.
3. Pull down to remove cartridge and dispose.

**Installing new cartridges**

1. Mark each cartridge with an install date in the space provided on cartridge label.
2. Match the inlet and outlet valve on the cartridge to corresponding port within the manifold and insert the cartridge. (Figure 1)

   [image]
3. Making a clockwise, quarter turn, twist the cartridge into locked position. (Figure 2) [image]
4. To replace the polishing filter, the tubing needs to be removed from the old filter. Check both ends of 3/8” tubing for any scratches. If scratches exist, please use a utility knife and make a straight cut to remove any imperfections on tubing. (Figure 3) [image]Connect the tubing to the new polishing filter with the “FLOW” arrow pointed in the direction of the faucet.
5. Make sure all cartridges are locked in place, and close tank valve, then turn back on the inlet water valve.

   - Run water for 10 minutes through the faucet in order to flush pre-filters and carbon post-filter.
   - Check system thoroughly for leaks.
6. Reinstall the RO membrane, turn on tank valve. Wait for RO tank to refill before product water is available.

http://sharpwater.com/files/support/CulliganAquaCleerMaintenanceDirections.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A great video by Culligan Water Lloydminster & North Battleford including

- how to turn off the filter's water supply,
- the tip on pushing in at 1:35,
- the reverse osmosis drain change,
- how the initial flushing should bypass the accumulating reservoir and kitchen pipes. (It dawned on me that flushing needs to be done step-by-step with adding finer filters so that each addition gets its coarser input flushed before flushing itself).

[Culligan How-to Change Aqua-Cleer Filters](https://youtu.be/-guPFrVEbgM)